# Massively Confused About Query Strings

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, alamofire, nsurl

I am using `AlamoFire` to make an API request. Connecting to the API has been pretty straight forward, what has been massively challenging is querying the API.

I am attempting to create a query string similar to this:

`https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/instruments/USD_CAD/candles?price=BA&from=2016-10-17T15%3A00%3A00.000000000Z&granularity=M1`

I feel like I have explored a lot of the internet for documentation on the subject and have come up short..

Does anyone have any resources or advice to share about query strings?

Comment: Is your question about how to generate a querystring for an AlamoFire request in Swift, or how to extract the components of a querystring? Or something else?

Comment: My question is how do I generate a querystring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make a query string is to use `URLComponents`, which handles all the percentage escape for you:

```
// Keep the init simple, something that you can be sure won't fail
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com")!

// Now add the other items to your URL query
components.path = "/v3/instruments/USD_CAD/candles"
components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "price", value: "BA"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "from", value: "2016-10-17T15:00:00.000000000Z"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "granularity", value: "M1")
]

if let url = components.url {
    print(url)
} else {
    print("can't make URL")
}
```

That is with pure Swift, which you should familiarize yourself with. Once you have master the basics, Alamofire can simplify it for you:

```
let params = [
    "price": "BA",
    "from": "2016-10-17T15:00:00.000000000Z",
    "granularity": "M1"
]
Alamofire.request("https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/instruments/USD_CAD/candles", parameters: params)
    .responseData { response in
        // Handle response
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate the help!